# How to increase email subject line character limit from 100 character

Tags: custom-object, email-template

I have read that Salesforce has increased character limit of subject line from 80 to 255. 
[One can check here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br7oAAC). I am having a custom object and from there I am trying to send a mail. This mail has a subject line which has more that 100 character so salesforce is showing an error " More than 100 characters are not allowed in Subject line". Please help me to resolve this problem and it is very urgent.
**Rectification**: We have a custom button on Activity History ('Send Email'). By using it we send mail to clients. Custom button code is given below:

```
location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?p3_lkid={!Operation__c.Id}&p2_lkid={!Operation__c.ContactId__c}&retURL=/{!Operation__c.Id}&p4={! 
IF( 
   ISPICKVAL(Operation__c.Current_Status__c, 'Final Mail Sent'), 
   Operation__c.Opportunity_Owner_Email__c, 
   IF( 
      OR( 
         ISPICKVAL(Operation__c.Current_Status__c, 'Documents Check Pending'), 
         ISPICKVAL(Operation__c.Current_Status__c, 'Signing Documents Sent'), 
         ISPICKVAL(Operation__c.Current_Status__c, 'Name Approved'), 
         ISPICKVAL(Operation__c.Current_Status__c, 'TM Application Filed'), 
     ), 
     Operation__c.OPE_Member_Email__c&","&Operation__c.Opportunity_Owner_Email__c, 
     Operation__c.OPE_Member_Email__c))}'
);
```

Comment: Have you set the API version to the latest (30) in the Apex code that sends the email?

Comment: I have edited my question Keith. We are using standard Salesforce functionality through simple custom button.

Comment: This was increased in Winter'11 (API 20.0, or 21.0..?) so one might hope @Rohit s work was long after that. Could I perhaps suggest you check your custom validation rules, because the wording of that error message is not one familiar to me (or Google) as a standard Salesforce response.

Comment: Can you provide the code for your custom button? I just tried out some apex that sends an email with the Subject larger than 255 characters and no error happened.

Comment: ok @BarCotter I have edited my question as per your requirement.@Simon there are no validation rules as such for emails in my org. I have google it, all are saying that it has been increased to 255 characters.

Comment: I can enter a subjects larger than 100 characters when I navigate to https://login.salesforce.com/email/author/emailauthor.jsp. Could your code be throwing that error?

Comment: @BarCotter: We have email templates in folders. So we select the template which is present in that folder and all merge fields automatically gets field according to the custom object record. We always use Custom( without using letterhead) option for new template.

Comment: @BarCotter: I forgot to mention that subject is predefined and we provide it while creating the new template by above said process.(as in last comment)

Comment: the standard salesforce page is not throwing that error when I try it.

Comment: @BarCotter I raised a case in salesforce and they confirmed that the limit is still 100 characters for subject line. They provide me link of the idea to vote for it : https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZVCnAAO. So I change my subject line of Email template to less than 100 characters. This is the solution of my problem. If you have another say. Please let me know.

Comment: @Rohit can you add this as the solution and accept it? This comment is hidden below the fold and isn't easily found.

Comment: Hi Heber, I have done the same. I hope you concern has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to this question provided by salesforce developer support team**  when I raised a case to them.

They confirmed that the limit is still 100 characters for subject line. They provide me a link of the idea to vote for it : [Vote here](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZVCnAAO). So I change my subject line of Email template to less than 100 characters.

Thanks for everyone's time.